# Custom Post Type Category Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post_type => book-site and loads of Book site categories like parent and child for e.g Parent Category (All Books Sites). Under all book sites, I have child categories:

> All book sites
>    - English book sites (6 posts)
>    - German book sites (5 posts)

When someone clicks the English book site, the link should show 6 posts, and 5 for German. If someone picks "All book sites" the parent link should show all posts for the user to click on. How can I create this template?

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any template, only pass the taxonomy url.
By default the archive.php file loads and that exactly shows the results as your requirement.

If you want to change html or any other stuff you can create template ( Archive Page) for your custom post type like archive-custom_post_type.php

For more details of wordpress template hierarchy visit [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)